# Losing workflow assoication to sharepoint list

Tags: list, associations, workflow, settings

I have an SPD2013 workflow on a 2010 platform.  Ever so often, I lose the association between the list and the workflow.  The workflow is not listed when viewing workflow settings for the list.  In SharePoint Designer I can see, edit, check for errors and re-publish the workflow.  After that the workflow will appear in Workflow Settings for the list. My question is why am I losing the association in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Catherine,

The problem is that Microsoft, in an effort to reduce the possibility of the size of our lists getting out of control and significantly slowing data retrieval, has set the (hidden) Workflow Auto Cleanup timer to "delete tasks and workflow instances which have been marked complete" after 60 days. According to Microsoft, workflow history "is not intended to be used to audit workflow events..."

I haven't worked anything out yet, but there is quite a bit of information available from Michael Allen at http://mallen22842.blogspot.com/2013/10/sharepoints-automatic-workflow-cleanup.html. Best of luck to you...

Troy